# Finding sum of coefficients of permutations of function compositions

Tags: functions, permutations, recurrence-relations

I have a pair of functions:
$$
\begin{align}
  g(x) &= 3 x \\
  h(x) &= -4 x ^ 3
\end{align}
$$
I want to compose $g$ and $h$, applying each $N_g$ and $N_h$ times, respectively. A few examples for $N_g = 3$ and $N_h = 2$:

$$
\begin{align}
F_0(x) &= g(g(g(h(h(x)))))) \\
F_1(x) &= g(g(h(g(h(x)))))) \\
F_2(x) &= g(g(h(h(g(x)))))) 
\end{align} \\\\
...
$$

In this way, I'm permuting the order of function applications. The end result I'm after is the value of:

$$
S(x) = \sum_{i=1}^{{N_g + N_h \choose N_g}} F_{i-1}(x)
$$

That is, the sum of all permutations of those function applications. The result will look like $S(x) = c x ^ {3 ^ {(N_h)}}$, I just don't know how to efficiently find $c$.

What I've tried? Well, this is where I'm stuck. I see how if $h(x)$ were linear I could solve this- it'd just be ${N_g + N_h \choose N_g} (-4)^{N_h}3^{N_g}$, but that cubic term is really giving me trouble.

---

For context, this problem stems from an attempt to calculate $\sin(\theta)$ for large floating-point exponentials (I'm a programmer, not a mathematician). I figure that I can use the identity:

$$
\sin(3\theta) = 3 \sin(\theta) - 4 \sin ^ 3 (\theta)
$$

I can convert the expression for $\theta$ to a power of $3$, compute a specific base case value, and apply the recurrence relation:

$$
R_{n+1} = 3 R_n - 4 R_n ^ 3
$$

This works, up to a point. The problem is I still run into hardware-related rounding errors. I'm seeking to reorder the computation to minimize these errors. It doesn't seem like this is recurrence relation that will have a closed-form solution, so I've settled for calculating expanding the relation and instead finding a closed-form solution for the coefficients of each term (this question).

Even if this approach is doomed / won't work due to other accuracy problems or performance issues, I'd still like to learn how to solve a problem like this.

Comment: Have you considered appealing to periodicity? That is find $k$ and $r$ such that: $\theta = 2\pi*k+r$ where $r\in [0,2\pi)$ and then $sin(\theta) = sin(r)$. For example 370 degrees and 10 degrees have the same location on the unit circle so they will have the same (x,y) coordinates etc. The $y$ coordinate being sin of course.

Comment: @KevinS yes, the issue with that is $\theta$ is an large floating-point exponential, and I'd have to evaluate before doing the floored division, resulting in huge rounding errors. $\theta$ can be something like $17.7^{130}$. I can't use modular exponentiation by squaring either, because the relation $a b \% m = ((a \% m) \times (b \% m)) \% m$ only holds if $a$ and $b$ are both integers (where $\%$ denotes remainder after floored division).

Comment: I thought about doing $sin(a^b) = sin(e^{ln(a^b)}) = sin(e^{bln(a)})$ to maybe reduce the base number involved, but that is more computation with numerical versions of transcendental functions and lead to a difference in answers (at least on my phone calculator). So I believe in your choice to use a trig identity, except I'm not sure how the recurrence relation comes in?